# Where can I find a satellite/space debris database with object masses

Tags: debris, two-line-elements, reference-request

The title pretty much says it all. As far as I can tell the default method by which space debris objects are tracked/stored in a database is using two line element sets. However these have no way to get the object mass (again, as far as I understand?). So is there another data set that can be brought inline with TLEs (maybe by the satellite ID?)

Comment: If there is small debris trackable by radar but of unknown size, shape and material, how should we know the mass? Debris resulting from a collision between two satellites, if you know the mass of both satellites before collision and the number of detected debris objects you may guess a mean mass ignoring the mass of debris objects too small for detection.

Comment: Also, even for active satellites, their mass changes over time as they expend stationkeeping or maneuvering fuel.

Comment: @Uwe this is all true, yet there are models used to estimate space debris growth - these models must have the mass of the object to work!

Comment: @organicmarble for most satellites the change in mass from propellant change is (reasonably) small as a percentage of the total mass (at least AFAIK).

Comment: @user6916458 half their mass can be propellant for a geo comsat. See page 8-9 here https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19920019663.pdf

Comment: @OrganicMarble true, but that reference includes the mass of the apogee manoeuvre (presumably for circularisation from transfer orbit) that's 90% of the propellant mass and not something that would be difficult to track (eg. if it's in transfer orbit it has the mass, if it's not it's lost the mass).