# How to access satellite & debris data categorised by intended purpose?

Tags: artificial-satellite, debris, space-art, space-track

I'm working on an art project which requires satellite data (active, inactive, as well as debris), so I was on Space Track. Does the NORAD ID or some other field help retrieve information about the mission objective or the intended uses of the satellite? Or is there another database I should be referring to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `OBJECT_TYPE` in Space-Track's GP data will tell you debris vs payload etc. Specific intended use is not present in that database.

Comment: There was a different but similar question within the last year with some overlapping answers referring to Space Track and the Satcat in Celestrak, there are codes for "rocket body" "debris" "payload" "functional" and "dead" or something like that. I'll look for it now.

Comment: This is not it, but it's somewhat related [Where can I find a satellite/space debris database with object masses](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43207/12102)

Comment: @uhoh just checked out CelesTrak and there seems to be additional information for each satellite's purpose. Eg: https://celestrak.org/satcat/1963/1963-019.php#A So, thanks for your tip! Do you know how I could download this data? Or is it as simple as requesting the author?

Comment: @sub511 https://celestrak.org/satcat/search.php

Comment: @sub511 click on one of the two format options for `Raw SATCAT Data`at https://celestrak.org/satcat/search.php